# OBJ not importing correctly?

Tags: texturing, obj

[[image: a new view][1]]I dont know whats going on, I am relatively new to blender although I have used it for a decent amount of time. The problem is that every time I import an OBJ the textures always comes out very glitched looking. I have imported before and this never happened until I recently reinstalled it and now ever OBJ turns out like this...
help?[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the weird thing on her mouth? Or is there something else wrong with these textures? If so, please show us the bad textures in the UV editor.

Comment: Agreed. It isn't clear from the picture exactly what the problem is. Consider a closer up image, as well as a more involved description of what went wrong, what you expect to happen instead, and if possible, what you have tried already.

Comment: I dont really know what it is to be honest the model just isnt complete with obj but with fbx the model looks normal. There are like triangles on the coat which shouldnt be there and theyes seem to be behing the face. I dont really know myself what I am seeing.

Comment: A blend mode problem maybe. Try setting blend mode on the materials to "Alpha Hashed".